# Adding padding to a columns adding up to 100%

Tags: html, css

I have three divs inline-blocked with a width of 33% each:

```
<div>
    <div class="third">hello</div>
    <div class="third">hello</div>
    <div class="third">hello</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.third {
    width: 33%;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

But once I add padding to the divs, it pushes the width of the columns up and they wrap to the next line:

```
.third {
    padding:10px;
}
```

Is there anyway I can prevent the padding from increasing the size of the div? I just want the content to be pushed inward.

Fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/chdehewh/

Thanks!

Comment: `* { box-sizing: border-box }`

Comment: Just so you know, you can get perfect thirds with `width: calc(100% / 3);`

Comment: @David this is not compatible with IE 8. And IE 9 have partial support...

Comment: It's a joke. Good appointment ;)

Answer (score 1):

Box sizing defined as border box makes paddings and borders included in the total width

```
.third {
    width: 33%;
   display:inline-block;
   background-color:yellow;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

See it working:
http://jsfiddle.net/chdehewh/2/

Also I included a trick to avoid spaces with inline block elements. Take a look

Comment: `-moz-box-sizing: border-box` too unless you want a nasty problem in firefox.

Comment: @David in what year do you live? I am in 2015 with firefox v40 with autoupdater....

Comment: Some people do not use the latest version of browsers. Some people are still using IE 6 and safari 5.1. You have to code for everyone, not just people on the latest versions.

Comment: So you must to recommend to no use of display inline block, IE 6 doesn't support it!!! So IE6 is died, and the user quota on this browsers is 0.001%. Firefox updates itself automatically. Don't worry.

Comment: This is why you program both. You would use width: 33%; width: calc(100% / 3); for maximum coverage. I was taught that you support everyone for as long as you can, and actually browser usage of FF 28 and earlier is more like 0.05%. Calm down. Completeness is better than incompleteness.

Comment: I am joking, sorry if I disturb you :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to tweak a couple of things in your fiddle to get it to work.

First, you'll want to set [`box-sizing: border-box;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) on your `.third-with-padding` class.

Next, you'll need to remove the spaces in between your divs. Spaces show up as if they were in text when using `display: inline-block;`. If you don't want to eliminate your space characters (keep code cleaner), you can use floats, flexbox, `display: table`, or a myriad of other solutions.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <div class="third-with-padding">
        hello
    </div><div class="third-with-padding">
        hello
    </div><div class="third-with-padding">
        hello
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.third-with-padding {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 33%;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:yellow;
    padding:10px;
}
```